# Deallocating keyboard as player while using Xbox controllers on Windows 10

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, windows-10

I have this issue, when playing games with controllers, that Windows 10 thinks that my keyboard is one of my players, and this means that I can't use one of my controllers as a player. Is there a way to deallocate my keyboard as a player?

I am not 100% sure that the keyboard is the source of the problem.
At the moment, I have 4 controllers plugged in. These are player 1, 2, and 4.

When I plug a 4th controller in, it does not recognize as player 3.

When I unplug them all and plug them all in, the last controller is always not recognized - player 3. My guess is that the keyboard is being player. Restarting helps, but the problem always reoccurs.

Comment: Maybe I would understand if I played games on Windows 10, but this seems very strange. Why does that prevent you from using your controller?

Comment: I've edited the question with more detail.

Comment: Okay, that makes a little more sense. So, you suspect it's the keyboard, but the actual problem is that your controller isn't being recognized. This way, if someone has a solution to the core problem that doesn't involve the keyboard, they'll know to post it. Welcome to Arqade, by the way.

Comment: When we've had this issue, generally restarting the game and only using controllers to navigate the menus has worked.  Placing the keyboard away from the players helps with no one touching it.